# XState: Express that a context is only relevant for certain states

Tags: xstate, xstate-react

I have a React component, it can transition between different states based on mouse-events. A simplified example:

```js
type Point = {x: number, y: number};

type MouseState =
  | {name: "idle"}
  | {name: "touched", point: Point}
  | {name: "moving", originalPoint: Point, currentPoint: Point};

function MyComponent() {
  const [mouseState, setMouseState] = useState<MouseState>({name: "idle"});

  // onMouse* handlers with logic to transition between states

  return <div onMouseDown={...} onMouseMove={...} onMouseUp={...}>Hello</div>;
}
```

I thought of trying out XState, instead of useState and state-logic in event handlers.
I have this so far:

```js
const mouseMachine = createMachine(
  {
    id: "mouse",
    initial: "idle",
    states: {
      idle: {
        on: {
          MOUSE_DOWN: "touched"
        }
      },
      touched: {
        on: {
          MOUSE_UP: "idle",
          MOUSE_MOVE: "moving"
        }
      },
      moving: {
        on: {
          MOUSE_UP: "idle"
        }
      }
    }
  }
);

// ... and I use useMachine in the component
```

What is the recommended way to express that

- the `touched` state has a `point` property, and
- the `moving` state has `originalPoint` and `currentPoint` properties?

So far, I have found `context`, but as I understand, it has to be defined on the root node, and requires initial values. So I should do:

```js
// ...
context: {
  point: null,
  originalPoint: null,
  currentPoint: null
},
initial: "idle",
// ...
```

The above seems to me as if I did:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [point, setPoint] = useState<Point | null>(null);
  const [originalPoint, setOriginalPoint] = useState<Point | null>(null);
  const [currentPoint, setCurrentPoint] = useState<Point | null>(null);
  const [mouseState, setMouseState] = useState<"idle" | "touched" | "moving">("idle");

  // ...
}
```

I can work with it, but if there is a way, I prefer declaring on a type-level that `point` is only relevant for the `touched` state, and `originalPoint` and `currentPoint` are only relevant for the `moving` state.

Answer (score 3):

That feels like an OOP approach to me (no offence). Don't think that's possible or ever needed (in the world of state machines).

You should see the `context` as the state of the machine itself and state transition as a mean to keep that state up to date. State nodes don't have state themselves.

If you wanted to understand the distance traveled by the mouse, you probably just need a start & end position:

```js
{context: {start: null, end: null}}
```

Then you use state transitions to update that context e.g.,

- When `idle`, reset both `start` and `end`.
- When `touched` record the `start` position on entry
- When `moving` and mouse up, record the `end` position

State machines in XState are observables so you can create an observable that emits the distance as soon as both `end` and `start` aren't null.

Not sure if that completely answers your question but I hope it has shed some lights and/or offered a new perspective.

---

For the sake of completeness I should mention that it is encouraged to split complex machines into smaller machines that are either invoked or spawned upon state transitions. This may sounds like inheritance in OOP parlance but that'd be a wrong analogy IMHO.

---

Finally kudos for considering state machines for web apps! That option is often overlooked (or sometimes dismissed) but offer a superior computing model compared to React Hooks IMHO. Once you've grokked a few key concepts working with Hooks feels backward.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for a detailed answer. Yes, you helped me look at it from a new perspective.

Comment: I searched SCXML docs about this topic. The [W3 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#state) which [XState docs also refer to](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/scxml.html) call it `datamodel`, the [Apache Commons docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-scxml/guide/contexts-evaluators.html) call it `context`. They both suggest that `state` nodes can have their own context. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: The lib authors want to implement it but it's too complex to implement so far: https://github.com/statelyai/xstate/discussions/1975

I also can't find where the spec authors suggest context per state in W3 specs. They clearly do so in Apache Commons. Can you point the W3 one?

Comment: "Can you point the W3 one?": Section "3.3.2 Children" says the `<state>` element can have a `<datamodel>` child element. Section ["5.2 <datamodel>"](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#datamodel) says it encapsulates any number of `<data>` elements → for details, see section ["5.3 <data>"](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#data).